# UITableviewCell constraints with auto layout fail

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

Adding constraints to a view inside the UITableviewCell by clicking (on interface Builder mode) "**Add Missing constraints**" lead to a lot of misleading constraints adding automatically by the Xcode.

[image: All new constraints after clicking "Add new constraints" on Xcode 5 DP5]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Xcode 5 DP5** has **bugs** in adding constraints to a UITableviewCell!!!!!

Solution: upgrade to **Xcode 5 DP6** 
Now it works fine !!!